# Formatting an Array

Tags: swift

This formats my emoji perfectly:

```
lblEmoji!.text = String(format: "%C", 0xe04f)
```

However, as soon as I change the string to my son array it does not format correctly as an emoji

```
lblEmoji!.text = questionArray.objectAtIndex(currQuestionCount-1).valueForKey("quesimage") as? String;(format: "%C", 0xe04f)
```

Where is it I am going wrong?

Comment: What is `String;(format: "%C", 0xe04f)`, that makes no sense.  Are you trying to take a Unicode emoji value out of the `currQuestionCount` array and replace the label's text with the new emoji?

Comment: Yes, correct - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String;(format: "%C", 0xe04f)` is wrong.  I don't even know what you're trying to do here.

If the objects in `questionArray` have a String variable `quesimage` (which is your emoji value), why not just take that directly without initializing a new String?

```
if let str = questionArray.objectAtIndex(currQuestionCount-1).valueForKey("quesimage") as? String {
    lblEmoji!.text = str
}
```

or if you need to use a format string:

```
lblEmoji!.text = String(format: "%C", str)
```

If `quesimage` is a regular String representation of a UTF8 string, use a format string like so:

```
let utf8str = "0xe04f" // your value coming from quesimage

let emojiStr = String(format: "%C", arguments: [utf8str])
print(emojiStr) // ⑰
lblEmoji!.text = emojiStr
```

Comment: Thanks for replying JAL. Without the formatting, the label just displays the text value of the emoji code. having lblEmoji!.text = String(format: "%C", 0xe04f) formats it to display the picture emoji. For some reason, your last one shows an Asian char (I was getting same thing when I tried)

Comment: @BCLtd You're passing in the hardcoded value `0xe04f`.  Isn that the value you're trying to pull out of your array?

Comment: Well I want that value because thats the UTF-16 Hex code (I think its called), if you try the formatting line I showed before you see it converts it to the emoji

Comment: @BCLtd Is `quesimage` a UTF8 string?

Comment: It was just the UTF 16 string

Comment: Ah I think I see what you're saying.  I've edited my answer with a format string that may work for you.

Comment: It's still coming out with japanese/chinese chars

Comment: @BCLtd can you give me an example value of what `quesimage` is?  I can't seem to reproduce your issue on my end.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am using http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/212/nature/bird to get the codes - maybe you tell me which one will work? for my test I just tried with your example above